# python logging.basicConfig doesn't overwrite the existing log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, overwrite

I'm using Python `logging.basicConfig` method, passing it some arguments including `filemode = "w"`. If it's not specified, it defaults to `"a"`, appending. However, despite specifying it to overwrite the existing log file, it's yet appending.

```py
import logging
# add filemode "w" to overwrite
logging.basicConfig(filename = "sample.log", level = logging.INFO,filemode = "w")
logging.debug("This is a debug message")
logging.info("Informational message")
logging.error("An error has happened!")
```

Comment: I tried your code, works fine for me, it does overwrite the log file when `filemode = "w"`

Comment: I tried it again and again after a day but nothing new happened. It keeps appending. Finally I threw the logging section away!

Answer (score 5):

Use the below code and try -

`filemode = "w+"`

#### Example

```py
logging.basicConfig(filename = "sample.log",
                    level = logging.INFO,
                    filemode = "w+" )
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case:
same trouble in Google Colab:
`logging.basicConfig(filename="log_file", filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)`
Code does append the `log_file`, not overwrite...

I apologize in advance for the big message - I try to clarify all the points of the situation. I will make a reservation right away that this effect is not observed when the script is run in PyCharm.
I suppose that the problem lies in the fact that in Anaconda (similar to Google Colab, where I encountered the same problem), the code is not executed anew, but using the results of previous executions. The logging process according to the ideology is constantly ready for use from the moment the program is launched. This is probably why there is a rule: (PEP: 282, part "Loggers") *"... Otherwise,
if a logger with that name exists, it **is returned**. If not, a new
logger **is initialized** and returned ... "***In our case, we need to restart the Kernel to clear the contents of the file that stores the logs**. For the sake of curiosity, I will try to reset the storage of logs without restarting the Kernel, but this is already an abnormal mode.

https://github.com/python/peps/blob/master/pep-0282.txt#L220

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26965812)

Comment: Fixed, I hope now the message will be useful in finding a solution to the problem.